# Firefox drags div it self on second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have designed a slider like players volume sliders with jquery.but the problem is ONLY IN FIREFOX , first time when i drag slider it's normal but second time browser drags that div it self like dragging images.unless after first time drag i click on an empty area and drag the slider again.what is the problem here?
sorry for my bad english.

**EDIT :**

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bjChB

html:

```
<div id="btn_container">

    <div id="button"></div>

</div>
```

css:

```
div#btn_container{
width:200px;
height:60px;
position:absolute;
background:red;
margin:auto;
right:0;left:0;top:0;bottom:0;  
}
div#button{
width:60px;
height:60px;
background:blue;
position:absolute;
left:0px;top:0px;   
}
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var pressed = false;
    var $this;
    var x;
    $("div#button").mousedown(function(e){
        pressed = true;
        $this = $(this);
        var offset = $this.offset();
        var inside = e.pageX - offset.left;
        $(document).mousemove(function(e){
            if(pressed){
                var parentOffset = $this.parent().offset();
                x = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
                if( x <= $this.parent().width() - $this.width() + inside && x >= 0 + inside)
                    $this.css({"left":x - inside});
            }
        });
    });
    $(document).mouseup(function(){
        if(pressed){
            if( x > $this.parent().width() - $this.width() - 30)
                $this.animate({"left":$this.parent().width() - $this.width()} , 50);

            pressed = false;
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Post your code and we might help you!

Comment: i added the code but code not matters here.because it works on every other browser than firefox and i have seen this problem on other websites in firefox too.

Comment: Sure code matters! It is very hard to guess what browser inconsistencies you might have found. But a working jsfiddle would be great in this case.

Comment: thanks for answer.here is the live show of code.try to drag blue div 2 times or more without clicking other place in firefox. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bjChB

Comment: Something is very wrong with this code.  When it fails, the control box sticks to the mouse, even after releasing the mouse button, and that seems to be the at the root.

Comment: Here is the jsFiddle of the OP's code as he originally posted it: http://jsfiddle.net/qcEus/

Comment: thanks for jsfiddle.i added codepen on the post too.yes it sticks to mouse but the question is why just in firefox?

Comment: i think i found the solution.when dragging the div gets selected and this is the reason.check my own answer for question ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `e.preventDefault();` to your `mousedown` to prevent whatever behavior it is that firefox is trying to use.

Answer (score 0):

I added this codes to css and it prevents the div to get selected.this solved problem.

```
-moz-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
```